# How to get the discount of items

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables, one of them holds an initial discount for an item and the other holds a discount that a clerk may give in addition to the initial discount, also on that item. Any number of items can be sold and have discounts applied.

What I'm attempting to do here is group by order_id and get the total dollar amount for the discount. I don't have this correct because I am getting .19 cents when it should be roughly $5 something on a $10.00 purchase where each item was discounted 50%.

How do I calculate this?

```
SUM(price*quantity)*(SUM(a.discount)+b.discount) AS discount
```

Comment: Sounds like you have got your maths wrong

Comment: Yes, Andy, I believe I do. What I'm not clear on is when a clerk has say, 5 discounted items, each at 25% discount, by my math, using `SUM()` that would be a total of 125% discount, which is not correct.

Comment: So, there's an ORDERS table, and ORDER_ITEMS table, an INITIAL_DISCOUNTS table, an OPTIONAL_DISCOUNTS table?  The discount in the INITIAL_DISCOUNTS table is a percentage of the list price; the discount in the OPTIONAL_DISCOUNTS table is a percentage of the initially discounted list price (or is it also a percentage of the list price?)...the joining columns are...?

Comment: @Jonathan, Yes, but the initial discount is not its own table, just a field in the ORDER table. The applied discount is another field in the ORDER_ITEMS table. THe tables are joined on order_id. The values would be, for example, .5 for 50%.

Comment: What does 'applied discount' mean?  The sum of the initial (order-wide) discount and the optional (per-item) discount?  Please edit the question to explain what you really have as table structures, with illustrative data for a single order.  When you've written that out, the logic for the query will probably be obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a single order item, you have a price, a quantity, an initial discount (there is always a discount for every order, though it could be zero) and the optional discount associated with a particular order item. So, the tables are ORDER and ORDER_IITEMS.  Given that the discounts are stored as fractions (0.000 .. 1.000),
you probably need a computation based on:

```
(price * quantity * (initial_discount + optional_discount))
```

to get the discount for a single item; you aggregate across that entire expression.  So, you end up with something like:

```
SELECT Order_ID, SUM(price * quantity * (initial_discount + optional_discount))
  FROM Orders AS O
  JOIN Order_Items AS I ON O.Order_ID = I.Order_ID
 GROUP BY Order_ID;
```

Applying aliases to column names in the SUM:

```
SELECT Order_ID, SUM(I.price * I.quantity *
                     (O.initial_discount + I.optional_discount)) AS discount
  FROM Orders AS O
  JOIN Order_Items AS I ON O.Order_ID = I.Order_ID
 GROUP BY Order_ID;
```

Comment: @Jonathan, thanks. As you say, there can be an initial discount applied or not. If there is no discount, then the user will enter 0.00. The optional discount is known when the tables are joined. I will have two discount columns at that point. The clerk can decide to give an initial discount or not. Both discounts are totally optional. The applied discounts are arbitrary and discretion is left to the clerk.

Comment: @Jonathan, I forgot to mention that there is no discount table. The discounts are simply fields in the order and item_order tables.

Comment: @Jim: given the simpler schema that you ended up describing, the calculation is (much!) simpler -- and I've edited my answer to reflect that.  But it illustrates how important it is to give the full details in the question - people simply can't help you accurately if you don't state the problem accurately.

Comment: @Jonathan, thanks and I'm sorry for not explaining better but I feel like I've been beat with a hammer. :)  BTW: Your query is correct and gives the expected total.

Comment: So there is no SUM needed? Why is that?

Comment: There are two SUMs involved.  There's the 'per item' or 'horizontal' sum of two discounts reflected by `initial_discount + optional_discount` which gives the total fractional discount to apply to the particular item, and then there is the 'per order' or 'vertical' sum (represented by the SUM aggregate) for all the items in a specific order.

Comment: OK, thank you for the explanation. I have 4 other columns to calculate. Would you mind having a look to make sure that I have this correct?

Comment: @Jim: Edit the question with *all* the information that might be needed - both the information previously requested and the extra information about the extra calculations.  People will collectively look at what you have - it might be me or it might be someone else who looks at the extra.  I use a horizontal rule `<hr>` to identify when there is extra material in the question from what was originally there - or rework the question into an integrated whole and note that it was substantially rewritten.